# Why does function expect IO[ data ] instead of [[ data ]] Haskell

Tags: haskell

The following code fails with this error.

```
main.hs:30:13: error:
    • Couldn't match type: [[Octopus]]
                     with: IO a0
      Expected: IO a0 -> IO a0
        Actual: [[Octopus]] -> [[Octopus]]
    • In the first argument of ‘iterate’, namely ‘loopStage’
      In the first argument of ‘(!!)’, namely
        ‘iterate loopStage octopusMatrix’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: iterate loopStage octopusMatrix !! 100
   |
30 |     iterate loopStage octopusMatrix !! 100
   |
```

```
module Main where


data Octopus = Octopus {
    level :: Int,
    hasFlashed :: Int
} deriving (Show)


incrementOctopusEnergyLevelByOne :: Octopus -> Octopus
incrementOctopusEnergyLevelByOne (Octopus level hasFlashed) = 
    Octopus (level + 1) hasFlashed

incrementOctopusListEnergyLevelByOne :: [Octopus] -> [Octopus]
incrementOctopusListEnergyLevelByOne = map incrementOctopusEnergyLevelByOne

increaseAllEnergyLevel :: [[Octopus]] -> [[Octopus]]
increaseAllEnergyLevel = map incrementOctopusListEnergyLevelByOne

loopStage :: [[Octopus]] -> [[Octopus]]
loopStage octopus_matrix = do
    increaseAllEnergyLevel octopus_matrix

main = do  
    contents <- readFile "input.txt"
    let fileLines = lines contents
    let matrix = parseListOfStringsToMatrixOfIntegers fileLines
    let octopusMatrix = convertMatrixToOctopusMatrix matrix
    
    iterate loopStage octopusMatrix !! 100
    
    print octopusMatrix

parseStringToListOfIntegers :: String -> [Int]
parseStringToListOfIntegers string = map (read . (:"")) string :: [Int]

parseListOfStringsToMatrixOfIntegers :: [String] -> [[Int]]
parseListOfStringsToMatrixOfIntegers = map parseStringToListOfIntegers

convertIntToOctopus :: Int -> Octopus
convertIntToOctopus value = Octopus value 0 

convertListOfIntsToListOctopus :: [Int] -> [Octopus]
convertListOfIntsToListOctopus = map convertIntToOctopus

convertMatrixToOctopusMatrix :: [[Int]] -> [[Octopus]]
convertMatrixToOctopusMatrix = map convertListOfIntsToListOctopus
```

My question is, why does the loopStage function expect an IO value? It is clearly marked as [[Octopus]].

I tried removing the iterate, which makes the error message more defined.

```
main.hs:30:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected: IO [Octopus]
        Actual: [[Octopus]]
```

After further debugging, it seems like the error is on the return type of the functions, that it is returning a non IO'able version of [[Octopus]] matrix? This is my first time writing Haskell. I tried wrapping all the return values in IO, but couldn't find a solution

Comment: What do you expect that line of code to do? A "line of code" in a `do`-block (consisting of more than one line of code) is either a `let`, a bind (with the syntax `... <- ...`) or a monadic action (in this particular case, "monadic" happens to mean `IO`). This is why it expects that expression to be an `IO` action.

Comment: An example of an expression that *is* an `IO` action is `print 7`. An example of an expression which *is not* an `IO` action is `sum xs`.

Comment: The expression `iterate loopStage octopusMatrix !! 100` has to produce a value of type `IO a` for some type `a`. From that, the type checker infers what type `loopState` must have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, why does the `loopStage` function expect an `IO` value? It is clearly marked as `[[Octopus]]`.

Indeed the `loopStage` function does not expect `IO`. The issue is elsewhere.

Let's focus on these lines.

```
    contents <- readFile "input.txt"
    -- ...        
    iterate loopStage octopusMatrix !! 100
```

In this `do` block, `readFile` returns a value inside `IO`. Therefore, Haskell infers that `iterate loopStage octopusMatrix !! 100` must have type `IO something`.

Now, let's look at the `iterate` polymorphic type:

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

The result type of

```
iterate loopStage octopusMatrix !! 100
```

must then be `a` (the element type of `[a]`, which is returned by `iterate). Therefore, we must have

```
iterate loopStage octopusMatrix !! 100 :: a
loopStage :: (a -> a)
octopusMatrix :: a
a = IO something
```

Hence, we **expect**

```
loopStage :: IO something -> IO something
```

which copes with the **actual** type of `loopStage`:

```
loopStage :: [[Octopus]] -> [[Octopus]]
```

Note that the GHC error message is saying exactly this:

```
Expected: IO a0 -> IO a0
Actual:   [[Octopus]] -> [[Octopus]]
```

This means "You are trying to pass `loopStage` which has type `[[Octopus]] -> [[Octopus]]` to a function (`iterate`) which instead expects a type of the form `IO a0 -> IO a0`".

How to fix this? One has to avoid trying to "run" the result of `iterate` as if it were an IO action:

```
let newOctopusMatrix = iterate loopStage octopusMatrix !! 100
print newOctopusMatrix
```

Comment: It's also worth considering what should _happen_ when that line is reached. OP may mistakenly believe that the execution of `loopStage octopusMatrix` will somehow update the value of `octopusMatrix`. This is not the case. `iterate loopStage octopusMatrix !! 100` is just an expression that does nothing on its own.

Comment: True; also, the `do` in the definition of `loopStage` is redundant, as `do singleExpression` is exactly equivalent to `singleExpression`, regardless of the type of that expression. There's probably a misunderstanding of what exactly `do` means.